# Can I develop an iOS app with 3rd party framework of library?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, ios7, twitter-oauth

I am developing an app which contain twitter and facebook login. Using Account Store framework it is worked fine. But I want to create a custom login view through twitter or facebook. Some tutorial prefer STTwitter/MGTwitterEngine framework. Can I develop my with by using these framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing against using a third-party framework in an iOS app. If you can code it correctly, it should fly on the App Store.

A quick Google on `MGTwitterEngine` shows you how much usage there is in iOS 7 for this framework.

Also, using `Accounts.framework` doesn't prevent you from customizing your login view and most certainly doesn't require you to use a completely separate API/toolset for the device.